# How to get attribute value in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I checked other's questions and still can't make this code work. I get `undefined`

```js
$('a').on('click', () => {
  console.log($(this).attr('data-target'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#er" data-target="SDfdf">Click me</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('a').on('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.dataset.target)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#er" data-target="SDfdf">Click me</a>
```